# Regular expression for exploding route in Laravel4

Tags: php, regex, laravel-4

How to explode a laravel

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName() // IndexController@getRegister
```

Into array of: namespace, controller, method, action

I created the expr:

```
(.*)\\(.*)Controller@(get|post|put|delete|patch)(.*)
```

But it doesnt work for all of routes

```
Admin\IndexController@getIndex
Admin\IndexController@postIndex
Other\Namespace\Admin\IndexController@putIndex
Admin\IndexController@deleteGetAjaxSuper
Admin\IndexController@patchIndex
IndexController@getRegister
Other_IndexController@getRegister
IndexController@getRegister
IndexController@getRegister
```

http://regexr.com?389rh
It doesnt work for last 4 items.

Comment: That would be because your \\ is not optional in your regexp. Make it optional and it will work for the last 4 as well.

Comment: Hahaha :) I forgot about the ? option :)
Full correct regex is:
(.*\\\)?(.*)Controller@(get|post|put|delete|patch)(.*)

Comment: that depends on what you want to allow (and/or catch). (.*\\)? matches anything (or nothing) followed by a matched \ followed by a match of anything (or nothing). Or nothing at all. While (.+)\\?(.*) would match anything (or nothing) followed by an optional slash followed by a match of anything (or nothing). In other words: both do the same thing. However yours catches the \ in the first match, while mine doesn't catch the \ at all (as per the OP's regexp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't matching the last 4 items because the items do not contain a \ before the controller. Your regexp *requires* them to have it, and as such does not match it. The answer is to make the initial slash optional by using a ? (=0 or 1 occurrence), like so:

```
(.*)\\?(.*)Controller@(get|post|put|delete|patch)(.*)
```

On a sidenote, are you sure that a Controller have no specific name? ie. a controller just called "Controller" will match your regexp as well. To disallow that (and only allow [something]Controller) you can change the 2nd .* to .+ (so from 0 or more matches to 1 or more matches). Like so:

```
(.*)\\?(.+)Controller@(get|post|put|delete|patch)(.*)
```

And the same thing for your method (get|post|etc.):

```
(.*)\\?(.+)Controller@(get|post|put|delete|patch)(.+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will not have any space around there before the Controller

```
\S+Controller@(get|post|put|delete|patch)(.*)
```

using `.*` instead of `\S+` will work as well.

Comment: It wont, because I dont want to "cut" every string before the "Controller". I want to cut a string before Controller, but not far till the \. After the \ other cut expression should be used.